# Monitor process api calls windows 7 vb.net/C# or C++

Tags: vb.net, winapi, process, monitoring

Currently i'm working on a security monitoring app that continuously monitor new processes created.
For that im using wim and event watcher, witch works fine in VB.NET.
But there are 2 features that im missing.

I need to monitor process API calls, and I've been searching the web like mad, and come up empty.

Basically i need to monitor process `WaitForSingleObject`, `LoadLibraryA`, `CreateProcessW` and `WriteProcessMemory`. And registry access/changes as well.

Im hoping this can be done without a system wide hook, but form what i can find, it cannot be done via WMI.

So the question is, how to, and what can i do with managed code.

Comment: Any help or comments are much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna focus on the second point as i don't have experience on your first.

For checking if a process is signed i am using the sigcheck.exe from Mark Russinovich, because of the various methods it uses to verify files. Some are catalogsigned, some have the key embedded, there is iirc another weird method. There is no easy way to do it yourself. Had weird false detections with trying  self-built methods to cover all possibilities. Hope that info helps

Comment: Thanks. Ive looked in to the sigcheck tool as a plan B, because im not looking to validate the signature, is mere a question of checking if a process has a signature or not.